# c# regex matches exclude first and last character

Tags: c#, regex

I know nothing about regex so I am asking this great community to help me out.
With the help of SO I manage to write this regex:

```
    string input = "((isoCode=s)||(isoCode=a))&&(title=s)&&((ti=2)&&(t=2))||(t=2&&e>5)";
    string pattern = @"\((?>\((?<DEPTH>)|\)(?<-DEPTH>)|.?)*(?(DEPTH)(?!))\)|&&|\|\|";
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0].Value);
    }
```

And the result is:

```
((isoCode=s)||(isoCode=a))
&&
(title=s)
&&
((ti=2)&&(t=2))
||
(t=2&&e>5)
```

but I need result like this (*without first/last "(", ")"*):

```
(isoCode=s)||(isoCode=a)
&&
title=s
&&
(ti=2)&&(t=2)
||
t=2&&e>5
```

Can it be done? I know I can do it with substring *(removing first and last character)*, but I want to know if it can be done with regex.

Comment: You're best off writing a parser for this. Regex is not the best tool for this. Yes balancing groups can ensure that you have an even number of open/closing parentheses, but you can't (not 100% properly anyway) do that **and** get values separated at the same time since the balancing group is meant to match the string as a whole and you need a regex that matches parts of it.

Comment: But regex give me exactly what I needed, just "(", ")" are to much.

Comment: I guess technically you can use `\(((?>\((?<DEPTH>)|\)(?<-DEPTH>)|.?)*(?(DEPTH)(?!)))\)|&{2}|\|{2}`. Obviously, I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish so I can't confirm it'll work for all your cases, but it'll at least work for your example. P.S. Using this regex you need to grab capture group 1 and if it doesn't exist use the match instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
\((?<R>(?>\((?<DEPTH>)|\)(?<-DEPTH>)|[^()]+)*(?(DEPTH)(?!)))\)|(?<R>&&|\|\|)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%28%28%3F%3CR%3E%28%3F%3E%5C%28%28%3F%3CDEPTH%3E%29%7C%5C%29%28%3F%3C-DEPTH%3E%29%7C%5B%5E%28%29%5D%2B%29*%28%3F%28DEPTH%29%28%3F!%29%29%29%5C%29%7C%28%3F%3CR%3E%26%26%7C%5C%7C%5C%7C%29&i=%28%28isoCode%3Ds%29%7C%7C%28isoCode%3Da%29%29%26%26%28title%3Ds%29%26%26%28%28ti%3D2%29%26%26%28t%3D2%29%29%7C%7C%28t%3D2%26%26e%3E5%29), grab Group "R" value.

**Details**

- `\(` - an open `(`
- `(?<R>`  - start of the `R` named group:

  - `(?>` - start of the atomic group:

    - `\((?<DEPTH>)|` - an open `(` and an empty string is pushed on the `DEPTH` group stack or
    - `\)(?<-DEPTH>)|` - a closing `)` and an empty string is popped off the `DEPTH` group stack or
    - `[^()]+` - 1+ chars other than `(` and `)`
  - `)*` - zero or more repetitions
  - `(?(DEPTH)(?!))` - a conditional construct that checks if the number of close and open parentheses is balanced
- `)` - end of `R` named group
- `\)` - a closing `)`
- `|` - or
- `(?<R>&&|\|\|)` - another occurrence of Group `R` matching either of the 2 subpatterns:

  - `&&` - a `&&` substring
  - `|` - or
  - `\|\|`  - a `||` substring.

[image]

C# code:

```
var pattern = @"\((?<R>(?>\((?<DEPTH>)|\)(?<-DEPTH>)|[^()]+)*(?(DEPTH)(?!)))\)|(?<R>&&|\|\|)";
var results = Regex.Match(input, pattern)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

### Brief

You can use the regex below, but I'd still strongly suggest you write a proper parser for this instead of using regex.

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%28%28%28%3F%3E%5C%28%28%3F%3CDEPTH%3E%29%7C%5C%29%28%3F%3C-DEPTH%3E%29%7C.%3F%29*%28%3F%28DEPTH%29%28%3F!%29%29%29%5C%29%7C%26%7B2%7D%7C%5C%7C%7B2%7D&i=%28%28isoCode%3Ds%29%7C%7C%28isoCode%3Da%29%29%26%26%28title%3Ds%29%26%26%28%28ti%3D2%29%26%26%28t%3D2%29%29%7C%7C%28t%3D2%26%26e%3E5%29)

```
\(((?>\((?<DEPTH>)|\)(?<-DEPTH>)|.?)*(?(DEPTH)(?!)))\)|&{2}|‌​\|{2}
```

#### Usage

[See regex in use here](https://ideone.com/NNeJok)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = "((isoCode=s)||(isoCode=a))&&(title=s)&&((ti=2)&&(t=2))||(t=2&&e>5)";
        string pattern = @"\(((?>\((?<DEPTH>)|\)(?<-DEPTH>)|.?)*(?(DEPTH)(?!)))\)|&{2}|\|{2}";
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Success ? match.Groups[1].Value : match.Groups[0].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Result

```
(isoCode=s)||(isoCode=a)
&&
title=s
&&
(ti=2)&&(t=2)
||
t=2&&e>5
```

Comment: Thank you. I will check how to write parser in c#. Sure there is common pattern. It will probably be faster then regex.

Comment: @Makla It's definitely the best way to go about this. It's a lot easier than trying to figure out a regex (think of the next programmer that has to read this and decipher the thing). It also allows you to finetune it to your exact needs and ensure special cases are accounted for.